# How to create map marker to show multi users' facing direction by here sdk?

Tags: here-api

I want to create a mobile application that can show where is your friends and in which direction they are facing. I want to use positionIndicator at first but I can't create one more positionIndicator on the map view. Then I turned to MapMarker, But I found I can't rotate it and scale it. And I tried MapLocalModel, but I don't think it's a good idea to use a 3d module to render a 2d object. Then I think I should create a new MapObject class. But the constructor of MapObject is package protect. I can't call it or override it. So, what's the correct way to implement it?

Comment: Rotation is the restriction in map marker object, however can you please write us back with your use case how significant is rotation and scaling for the application

Answer (score 0):

MapLocalModel in general is the right approach for a marker which could be rotated. Agree that for 2D object MapLocalModel is not the best approach however the alternative would be rotating the image used for MapMarker itself which might also have some performance hit.